# FOR XML in SQL Server: Elements based on common values of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I'm using FOR XML to create an XML file out of SQL queries. I want to have elements based around common values for a particular column, in this case "location":

```
location    team    score
Adelong     SFP     104
Adelong     LIB     189
Adelong     CDP     9
Hurstville  SFP     14
Hurstville  LIB     64
Hurstville  CDP     13
```

I can easily convert his into XML row-by-row like so:

```
SELECT(SELECT location, team, score FROM MyTable FOR XML PATH('node'), TYPE ) FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
```

Which produces XML that looks liks this:

```
  <node>
    <location>Adelong</location>
    <team>SFP</team>
    <score>104</score>
  </node>
  <node>
    <location>Adelong</location>
    <team>LIB</team>
    <score>189</score>
  </node>
  <node>
    <location>Adelong</location>
    <team>CDP</team>
    <score>9</score>
  </node>
```

But what I actually want is this:

```
<location name="Adelong">
    <node>
        <team>SFP</team>
        <score>104</score>
    </node>
    <node>
        <team>LIB</team>
        <score>189</score>
    </node>
    <node>
        <team>CDP</team>
        <score>9</score>
    </node>
</location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ad hoc derived table that gets the distinct locations, select the locations from it and get the teams and scores in a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t1.location [@name],
       (SELECT t2.team,
               t2.score
               FROM mytable t2
               WHERE t2.location = t1.location
               FOR XML PATH('node'),
                       TYPE)
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.location
                    FROM mytable t1) t1
       FOR XML PATH('location');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=0f8450d7c21fbdf3c0d7199530684cd8)

Comment: Good answer, +1 form my side. Just a tiny hint: You might want to read [Aaron Bertrands "Performance Surprise"](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct) concerning `DISTINCT` vs. `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is XQuery FLWOR expression based solution.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [location] VARCHAR(20), team CHAR(3), score INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (location, team, score)
VALUES
('Adelong'     ,'SFP',  104)
,('Adelong'    ,'LIB',  189)
,('Adelong'    ,'CDP',  9  )
,('Hurstville' ,'SFP',  14 )
,('Hurstville' ,'LIB',  64 )
,('Hurstville' ,'CDP',  13 );
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT *
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('<root>
{
   for $x in distinct-values(/root/r/location)
   return <location name="{$x}">
   {
        for $y in /root/r[location/text() = $x]
        return <node>
            {$y/team}
            {$y/score}
        </node> 
    }
    </location>
}
</root>');
```